# Magento Admin Layout and Template

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am new in Magento. I am learning Magento Module development. I am trying to follow this (http://www.opensourceforwebtechnologies.com/create-custom-admin-module-in-magento/) tutorial. In this regard my code is as below.

**Easylife_All.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Easylife_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Location of this file is

[image]

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>


    <admin>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>admin_helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>easylife/helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <menu>
            <helloworld translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                <title>My Module</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <set_time>
                        <title>Address Book</title>
                        <action>admin_helloworld/adminhtml_index</action>
                    </set_time>
                </children>
            </helloworld>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>


    <global>
        <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Block</class>
            </helloworld>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>helloworld_resource</resourceModel>
            </helloworld>
            <helloworld_resource>
                <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <helloworld>
                        <table>helloworld</table>
                    </helloworld>
                </entities>
            </helloworld_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <helloworld_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Easylife_Helloworld</module>  
                    <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Model_Resource_Setup</class> 
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_setup>
            <helloworld_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_read>
            <helloworld_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_write>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Location of this file

[image]

**IndexController.php**

```
class Easylife_Helloworld_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

Location of this file is

[image]

**helloworld.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <helloworld_adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="helloworld_grid" type="helloworld/adminhtml_grid" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </helloworld_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

Location of this file

[image]

**helloworld.phtml**

```
<h1>Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
```

Location of this file

[image]

I am trying to browse below url

**http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin_helloworld/adminhtml_index/index/key/0c82140c8238734651f876e83e2522f5/**

I am getting blank page like below

[image]

Could anyone say why it is happening so ??

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**Block folder**

Location of block folder

[image]

**Helloworld.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_Helloworld_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function Test_Method()
    {
        $result = '';
        $collection = Mage::getModel('helloworld/helloworld')->getCollection()->setOrder('id', 'asc');
        foreach ($collection as $data)
        {
            $result .= $data->getData('firstname') . ' ' . $data->getData('lastname') . ' ' . $data->getData('phone') . '<br />';
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Success!!');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new file in controller/Adminhtml and with the name HelloworldController.php and write code in the file

```
class Easylife_Helloworld_Adminhtml_HelloworldController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

public function indexAction()
{
    $Block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('helloworld/adminhtml_helloworld');
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_addContent($Block)
        ->renderLayout(); 
}  }
```

and create a file in block/adminhtml/Helloworld/Edit create Form.php file With following code

```
class Easylife_Helloworld_Block_Adminhtml_Helloworld_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{
 protected function _prepareForm()
 {
    echo "11111111";
   return parent::_prepareForm();
 }}
```

Comment: Sorry @murtuza. Your solution is not working. Thanks

Comment: I am getting a **404 Page not found** error. Thanks

Comment: have you created adminhtml.xml file??

Comment: No, I have not created adminhtml.xml file. Thanks

Comment: adminhtml.xml file necessary for admin routing and display your extension in navbar of admin so create that file.

Comment: I created a **adminhtml.xml** file inside **etc** folder. code is as like below


`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <helloworld translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>My Module</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <set_time>
                    <title>Address Book</title>
                    <action>admin_helloworld/adminhtml_index</action>
                </set_time>
            </children>
        </helloworld>
    </menu>
</config>`

Comment: But I am getting same blank white page like before. Thanks

Comment: what exactly you want to display?

Comment: phtml used for frontend display not for back end

Comment: block folder use for admin display

Comment: give me full detail for block folder structure and file with in that you have created

Comment: Thanks @murtuza for your reply. I added some update with block folder location and code. I think that will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks @murtuza for your reply. I think it is better if you follow the tutorial (which link can be found in the question). It is better if you help me to find out the mistake/error of the tutorial. BTW your solution provide me some error to me. Thanks.